# python coroutines do not run one by one?

Tags: python, coroutine

I have a function which trigger events at certain frequency, and a coroutine task as action.  Below is my implementation (function `wrapper`), however it seems they run at the same time, what happened?

```py
import time
import asyncio
start = time.time()

def main(callback):
    for i in range(5):
        time.sleep(.5)
        callback()

async def sub_task():
    print("sub_task", time.time() - start)


#-----------------------
# below is what i do 
def wrapper():
    asyncio.create_task(sub_task())

main(wrapper)

# output: why don't they run at 0.5 sec interval?
#sub_task 2.57704758644104
#sub_task 2.57704758644104
#sub_task 2.57704758644104
#sub_task 2.5780487060546875
#sub_task 2.5780487060546875
```

---

I added some comments if above description might be misleading.
The code is tested in a clean jupyter notebook.
[image]

Comment: You aren’t running any event loop anywhere!?

Comment: Forget to mension, i ran it in jupyter notebook, so no asyncio.run here

Comment: One question:
In my answer, I presumed you needed asyncio for something not shown in the example, but, if you're running in a jupyter ntoebook, what do you need the async for, exactly?

Comment: While synchronous code runs, the asynchronous tasks can't be executed (in the same thread) so they accumulate and are executed when the synchronous code ends (after the `sleep`s).

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thx, explanation is clear. Any workaround? So as to call async function inside non-async function without delay

Answer (score 2):

There are several things wrong with your code, and it's quite hard to explain them all, so, instead, I'll show you the code that does what you expect it to do, and then explain it:

```py
import time
import asyncio
from typing import Coroutine, Callable

START = time.time()

async def run_loop(callback: Callable[[], Coroutine]) -> None:
    for _ in range(5):
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
        await callback()

async def sub_task() -> None:
    print("sub_task", time.time() - START)

async def main() -> None:
    await run_loop(sub_task)

asyncio.run(main())
```

```
sub_task 0.5007944107055664
sub_task 1.0015990734100342
sub_task 1.5024292469024658
sub_task 2.003257989883423
sub_task 2.504088878631592
```

So, how does this work?
First of all, I am sure that you are aware that you do need to run all of this in async with the current configuration. I presume the async-nes comes in in a part not shown in the example.
EDIT: as Michael Butscher pointed out, This also explains why your current code runs all at once: in a notebook, when you do not have a running event loop and try to add to it anyway, the loop will be run last, after the blocking code is done. In a terminal, where I tested it, it will not run at all.

Then, you are not running a async loop in your current code. I presume that's also just because you forgot to add it to the example. In this case, I am using `asyncio.run` to start the loop and make sure we're in a async function for the rest of the example. It is important to note that `run_loop` also needs to be an async function: otherwise, it needs to create its own asyncio loop every time it wants to run, blocking everything else. I presume there are other async things you are doing, so, this one needs to be async, too.

Then, there are several things to note:
first of all, `time.sleep` blocks *everything,* also async code. If you do not want the sleep to block something other than the current async function, you should use `await asyncio.sleep()`

Then, in your `create_task` you were calling the function `sub_task` this returns a future. What you forgot is that a future can only be awaited once. If you want to await an `async` function multiple times, you need to call it multiple times. I tried to make this more clear with type annotations.

I hope that clears things up. :-)

Comment: Thank you. What if my main function cannot be defined with async? This is my actual situation: 1) the main function belongs to an existing package, it only expose a callback api, and it cannot be croutine function 2)my sub_task function has to be croutine because i need to other croutine inside. So is it possible only   revising my wrapper function?

Comment: In that case, simply change `asyncio.create_task` with `asyncio.run` in your `wrapper()` function. It is not pretty, but it will at least do what you expect it to do. There might be something cleaner possible with asyncio.gather(), but, for that, I would need to know more about your usecase.